# Hibernate merge does not work with attribute as collection

Tags: java, hibernate, collections, merge

I am new to Hibernate and try to persist an entity that contains a collection.

I have my class User that contains an attribute that is a Set.

```
class User{

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
   @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
   @Valid
   @Nullable
   public Set<Permission> getPermissions()
   {
      return permissions;
   }
}
```

When I update the user with a new Set of permissions and tries to save it the permissions is reset to the original value again, all the other values are updated, only the permission that is not.

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
   @Override
   public User update(User user)
      entityManager.merge(user);
      entityManager.flush(); 
      entityManager.refresh(user); 
      return user;
```

I have read about transitive persistence and detached objects but I still don't get it to work.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
@Override
public User update(User user)
    return entityManager.merge(user);
}
```

The other calls are unnecessary and clutter your code. And you ignore the result of `merge()`, which is the updated, attached version of the detached, left untouched, user passed as argument.

Also, note that since you have a cascade ALL on the association, the above will not only update the user fields and which permissions are associated to the user. It will also merge the permissions. So the state of the permissions of the user passed as argument will be copied to the attached versions of these permissions and be saved in database.

Comment: That is what I had from the beginning before I started elaborating. Doing that results in "A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance" or if I change to "orphanRemoval = false" that the Set of permissions is not updated.

Comment: Don't replace the collection itself. Add and remove elements to/from the collection. It's still not clear what you want to do. Do you want to modify and delete permissions or not?

Comment: I tried what I think you meant but I only get the new Permission back in User even though I add all the permissions              public User update(User user, Set<Permission> permissions)          { for (Permission p : permissions) {                      user.getPermissions().add(p);                                        }                                                                       User mergedUser = entityManager.merge(user);                                return mergedUser; }

Comment: If you want only those permissions, you should do `user.getPermissions().clear()` before adding the new permissions. Remove the old ones and add the new ones.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are replacing the entire collection?  I've found it's best to get the existing collection, and call .add() and .remove() on it to update it's contents rather than replacing the entire thing.

Also, you could try using @ElementCollection instead

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="PERMISSION",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")}
)
private Set<Permission> permissions;
```

The only caveat is that the Permission class must be marked with @Embeddable, and I don't believe you can directly query permissions as a top level object (you'd have to go through the user).  Also, the Permission object would not have a pointer back to it's user.

Here's a sample hql of how you'd query it:

```
 select p from User u join u.permissions p where p.name=?
```

Comment: I tried what I think you meant but I only get the new Permission back in User even though I add all the permissions @Transactional(readOnly = false)
   @Override
   public User update(User user, Set<Permission> permissions)
   {
      
      for (Permission p : permissions)
      {
         user.getPermissions().add(p);
      }
      User mergedUser = entityManager.merge(user);
      return mergedUser;
   }